# Help understanding DIV instruction in x86 inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, division

While reading through some source code in a GNU project, I came across this bit of inline assembly:

```
__asm__ (
  "divq %4"
  : "=a" (q), "=d" (r)
  : "0" (n0), "1" (n1), "rm" (d)
);
```

Here the variables `q`, `r`, `n0`, `n1`, and `d` are 64-bit integers.  I know enough assembly to get the gist of what this does, but there's some details I'm not certain about.

**What I understand:**

We're dividing the contents of the RAX register by `d`, placing the quotient in `q`, and placing the remainder in `r`.

**What I don't understand**

1. Why are there *three* inputs
   here?  We only need to input a
   dividend and a divisor, so what use
   could there be for 3 inputs?
2. I can't tell which of the inputs is the dividend.  More generally, I don't see anything actually
   being loaded into the RAX register,
   so how does it know what to divide by what?

Comment: +1 well-formatted question. I like the "what I understand" and "what I don't understand" sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the input operands specification:

```
: "0" (n0), "1" (n1), "rm" (d)
```

registers "0" and "1" are forced to `rax` and `rdx` because of the output specification:

```
: "=a" (q), "=d" (r)
```

And the `div` instruction family wants the numerator in `RDX:RAX`.  The divisor can be in a general purpose register (not otherwise used - ie., not `RAX` or `RDX`) or memory, which is specified by the "rm" constraint.  Registers `RDX`, `RAX`, and the divisor operand make up the 3 inputs.

So this will end up performing the division:  `n1:n0 / d` where `n1:n0` is a quantity loaded into `rdx:rax`.

Comment: do I understand correctly that this can be used to divide a 128 bit integer by a 64 bit integer? I knew that this was possible for the 32 bit register version, but never thought that it would hold for the 64 bit version, too.

Comment: @Jens: that's correct. But remember that (like the smaller operand division operations) if the quotient ends up being too large for the `rax` destination register you'll get a divide exception.

Comment: The quick way to test for this case is simply to make sure `rdx` is less than the divisor, in which case the division is safe.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly observe the `div` family works on the fixed registers `a` and `d`, `rax` and `rdx` for `divq`. The `a` register gets its input from `n0` which is aliased to the 0th register, namely `a`. `n1` is a dummy input aliased to `d`, probably just to ensure that this register is not used for other purposes.